# Add a search box to search content using %like%

Tags: php, search

I want to add a search box to search content using `%like%`.

I have try too much but get number of error.

I had apply query like this:

```
<?php
    //including the database connection file
    include_once("config.php");

    //fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
    ?>



      <html>
        <head>  
            <title>Homepage</title>
        </head>

        <body>
        <a href="add.html">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>

            <table width='80%' border=0>

            <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Update</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {      
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['age']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['email']."</td>";  
                echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";       
            }
            ?>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Which errors are you getting?

Comment: there's no `%like%` in your code. *"but get number of error"* - being?

Comment: i have remove it now. if you have solution then provide please

Comment: you've an answer below

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="POST">
<input name="search" type="text">
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<?php
if($_POST){
    $data = $_POST['search'];
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` LIKE '%$data%' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {      
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['age']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['email']."</td>";  
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
    }
}
?>
```

P.S. mysql is deprecated, use mysqli with good escaping or mysqli prepared statements or PDO

Comment: You should probably end each table row too -  echo "</tr>";

Comment: whatever, this part is a copy from his code anyway :D

Comment: I know it - I had actually written it as a comment for OP's question, but noticed your answer came in before I saved the comment. Figured I'd help OP by pointing it out in your answer. Thanks for the PS too, also something I wanted to mention.

Comment: if you have solution then solve it out

Comment: I already solved it?

Comment: you are not getting what i want to say

Comment: the table show all data what i just want to add a serch box over it so that item are easily searched

Comment: define the term "search" ... what do you want to search for?

Comment: Magus Infotech has only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat

Comment: any data from table like i have divesh in name feild i just search div and it show result for it. the code you provide not show all data before search

Comment: Ctrl + F .. Thats what u want ?